# How render body content without sidebar and header in rails4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, rendering, partial-views

I'm developing some rails application, I have a sidebar with treeview, some main content with CRUD forms and header of page.

But when I click new, or create, or show, rails reload all page.

What can I do to render just `yield` without sidebar and header of page?
( e.g. now my treeview collapse when I go from one page to other page ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Layout**

You'll be best reading up on the [`layouts`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#structuring-layouts) inside Rails -

Every time your application loads a view, it will wrap it with a `layout` - this is basically a way to define how your application *looks*

I would recommend looking at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` - this is the default / standard layout for your application, and is where your `sidebar` & other layout elements will reside

--

**Options**

The choice you have is to either use `conditions` to determine aspects of your layout, or simply use other layouts to determine a different look

To set the other layouts, you can do this:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def action
      layout "form" #-> will use app/views/layouts/form.html.erb
   end
end
```